# Location of virtual machines in mac for virtual box

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

What is the location of all .vbox files that are created in virtual box in a mac. And how can we delete it?

I mistakenly deleted virtualbox.app file from Applications and now I want to delete all the remains of all virtual box files.
I tried following things:

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 user  admin  102 Dec 19 19:57 vagrant
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1824496 Feb 21 17:17 com.vagrant.vagrant.bom
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel       240 Feb 21 17:17 com.vagrant.vagrant.plist
drwx------  5 root  wheel  170 Feb 21 16:59 ubuntu-cloudimg-precise-vagrant-amd64_1487725164672_27815
./private/var/root/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntu-cloudimg-precise-vagrant-amd64_1487725164672_27815:
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        3036 Feb 21 16:59 ubuntu-cloudimg-precise-vagrant-amd64_1487725164672_27815.vbox
-rw-------  1 root  wheel        3036 Feb 21 16:59 ubuntu-cloudimg-precise-vagrant-amd64_1487725164672_27815.vbox-prev
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel        24 Feb 21 17:17 vagrant -> /opt/vagrant/bin/vagrant
```

But I could not find the location of .vbox files to manually delete them.

Answer (score 0):

By default the .vbox files normally go into your users' home directory:

```
pwd
/Users/Astro58/VirtualBox VMs

total 264
drwx------@  6 lance  staff   204 Feb 22 19:03 ./
drwxr-xr-x+ 88 lance  staff  2992 Feb 22 16:11 ../
drwx------   6 lance  staff   204 Feb 22 19:50 Laravel_default_1487808229046_76286/
drwx------   7 lance  staff   238 Feb 20 12:53 legacy_default_1487457532080_39585/
```

You should be able to delete the "VirtualBox VMs" directory via the `rm` command or via the Mac Finder.

Comment: I deleted the vbox files and when I try to reinstall everything, it works fine. But then when I do vagrant up, it says that the machine with the same name already exists.

Comment: Sounds like you needed to do a `vagrant destroy` before your vagrant up.  If you still have a problem post your `Vagrantfile` and we can see if there's another problem.  What host software are you using, VirtualBox, VMWare, etc.?